# mysql use group by column in where condition

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1111

How can I make this query work :

```
SELECT column1.....,SUM(Hits) AS Hits   
FROM table 
WHERE  SUM(Hits) > 100
GROUP BY column1.....
```

The problem is the where clause, mysql display error :

```
Error Code : 1111
Invalid use of group function
```

I try to change the query to :

```
 SELECT column1.....,SUM(Hits) AS Hits   
    FROM table 
    WHERE  Hits > 100
    GROUP BY column1.....
```

It did not help.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT column1.....,SUM(Hits) AS HitsSum 
FROM table 
GROUP BY column1.....
HAVING HitsSum > 100
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that you can not use aggregate functions, or column aliases to derived columns using aggregate functions, in the `WHERE` clause.  These can only be used in the `HAVING` clause, which requires defining a `GROUP BY` clause (if it doesn't already exist).

I don't recommend using the column alias in `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses - there's a risk that the query will not be portable to other databases.  SQL Server is the only other database that I'm aware of that supports column aliases in the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses.

```
  SELECT t.column1....., SUM(t.hits) AS HitsSum 
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.column1.....
  HAVING SUM(t.hits) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1.....,SUM(Hits) AS Sum_Hits   
FROM table 
GROUP BY column1.....
HAVING Sum_Hits > 100
```